# Conversion of JSON object into class members in WEB API Post Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, vba, webhooks

I want to convert the following JSON object into class members:
{"notificationId":"29397081-d4ed-4d2a-a672-4e875eabf535",
"eventType":"net.authorize.customer.paymentProfile.deleted",
"eventDate":"2019-08-15T15:36:34.7856727Z",
"webhookId":"183a9022-510b-4801-a50c-75ef7310844f",
"payload": 
{"customerProfileId":1920340068,
"entityName":"customerPaymentProfile",
"id":"1833395942"}}

I have tried using: 
Namespace transaction_

```
Public Class Payload
    Public customerProfileId As String = ""
    Public entityName As String = ""
End Class

Public Class transaction
    Public notification As String = ""
    Public eventType As String = ""
    Public eventDate As DateTime
    Public webhookId As String = ""
    Public payload As Payload = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Namespace

Didn't work. 
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you could use the Newtonsoft.Json nuget package, which has the method JsonConvert.DeserialzeObject(json).

example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Payload
{
    public string customerProfileId;
    public string entityName;
}

public class Transaction
{
    public string notification = "";
    public string eventType = "";
    public DateTime eventDate ;
    public string webhookId  = "";
    public Payload payload = null;
}

var myJson =  
 @"{""notificationId"":""29397081-d4ed-4d2a-a672-4e875eabf535"", ""eventType"":""net.authorize.customer.paymentProfile.deleted"", ""eventDate"":""2019-08-15T15:36:34.7856727Z"", ""webhookId"":""183a9022-510b-4801-a50c-75ef7310844f"", ""payload"": {""customerProfileId"":1920340068, ""entityName"":""customerPaymentProfile"", ""id"":""1833395942""}}";

Transaction myTransaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Transaction>(myJson);
```

Comment: Which class object can handle the JSON object passed via webhook to my web api ?

Comment: It is still giving transaction as null. Can you please suggest ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I run this code in a small console app to test it it works. Are you sure that the input you are providing to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() is correct?

Answer (score 0):

you also could use MongoDB.Bson nuget package. its a biger then Newtonsoft but allows easy mapping between your notificationId in JSON to your notifikation string

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Transaction
{
   [BsonElement("notificationId")]
   public string notification = "";
   public string eventType = "";
   public DateTime eventDate;
   public string webhookId = "";
   public Payload payload = null;
}

var myJson =
 @"{""notificationId"":""29397081-d4ed-4d2a-a672-4e875eabf535"", ""eventType"":""net.authorize.customer.paymentProfile.deleted"", ""eventDate"":""2019-08-15T15:36:34.7856727Z"", ""webhookId"":""183a9022-510b-4801-a50c-75ef7310844f"", ""payload"": {""customerProfileId"":1920340068, ""entityName"":""customerPaymentProfile"", ""id"":""1833395942""}}";

Transaction myTransaction = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Transaction>(myJson);
```